# Swift : Streaming / Writing out a CSV file

Tags: swift, csv

I am using my phone to record some sensor data and store it on device via SQLite via SharkORM(DBAccess).

I now want to write that data out to a CSV file however, I am  now up to 1.6 million records.

Currently, I am looping through 1000 records, adding them to a string and at the end writing them out.  However, there must be a better way to do it?

```
func writeRawFile()
    {
        let fileName = "raw"
        let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

        let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("csv")

        var data = "time,lat,lon,speed,x_acc,y_acc,z_acc,gyro_x,gyro_y,gyro_z,compass,orientation\r\n"

        let count = RawReading.query().count()
        var counter = 0;
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd H:m:ss.SSSS"

        for i in stride(from:0, to: count, by: 1000)
        {
            autoreleasepool {

                for result in RawReading.query().offset(Int32(i)).limit(1000).fetch()
                {
                    if let raw : RawReading = result as? RawReading
                    {
                        if (Double(raw.speed!) > 3.0) //1 Meter per Second = 2.236936 Miles per Hour
                        {
                            //print(df.string(from: raw.date!))

                            data += "\(df.string(from: raw.date!)),\(raw.lat!),\(raw.lon!),\(raw.speed!),\(raw.x!),\(raw.y!),\(raw.z!),\(raw.xx!),\(raw.yy!),\(raw.zz!),\(raw.compass!),\(raw.orientation!)" + "\r\n"

                            counter += 1
                        }

                    }
                }

                print ("Written \(i) of \(count)")

            }
        }

        print("Count \(count) \(counter)")

        //write the file, return true if it works, false otherwise.
        do{
            try data.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8 )
        } catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Open a [`FileHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filehandle) for writing, then build and write each line separately, so that you don't have to keep the entire file contents
in memory:

```
do {
    let file = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: fileURL)
    defer { file.closeFile() }

    for <... your loop ...> {
        let line = ... // build one CSV line
        file.write(line.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }

} catch let error {
    // ...
}
```

You can also write to a temporary file first and then rename it to the
actual file, in order to avoid a damaged file if anything
went wrong.